# After upgrading PHP-8.2 on Ubuntu virtualhosts doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, virtualhost, php-8

I checked all configurations several times. Everything seems to be OK.

```bash
sudo apache2ctl configtest

Syntax OK
```

```bash
apache2ctl -S

VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server XX.leaseweb.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost XX.leaseweb.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost XX0.ch (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/XX0.ch.conf:1)
                 alias www.XX0.ch
         port 80 namevhost XXloud.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/XXloud.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.XXloud.com
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

All Files are set with chown www-data:www-data

Permission setting:

```bash
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

VirtualHost-Setting with
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/XX0.ch.conf

```bash
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@XXloud.com
    ServerName XXloud.com
    ServerAlias www.XXloud.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/XX0.ch
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =XXloud.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.XXloud.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

```bash
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
    ServerAdmin webmaster@XXloud.com
    ServerName XXloud.com
    ServerAlias www.XXloud.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/XX0.ch
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains"
    </IfModule>
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/XX0.ch/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/XX0.ch/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Calling the Server trough IP-Address on a Site with phpinfo() works!

```bash
//http://XXX.XXX.62.175/index.php

phpinfo();
=> Shows correctly PHP Version 8.2.6
```

NO Error on restart Apache. Before the update everything works fine. Including SSL/TSL call.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
It was due to reinstalling Certbot

```bash
sudo apt install certbot python3-certbot-apache
```

After reinstalling, I had to renew the certificates and then everything went back to normal.

```bash
sudo certbot --apache
```

Please excuse the unnecessary call here.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading PHP from 8.0 to 8.2 on Apache and Ubuntu was easier than I thought, achieved with just five commands:

1. apt-get update
2. apt-get install php8.2 php8.2-cli php8.2-common php8.2-mysql php8.2-soap php8.2-bcmath php8.2-xml php8.2-mbstring php8.2-gd php8.2-curl
3. a2dismod php8.0
4. a2enmod php8.2
5. systemctl restart apache2

The existing configuration that you had should not be affected by the upgrade, concerning virtual hosts.